# SUmmation of natural logarithm

Tags: logarithms

Good day! Is there a  formula that approximate the summation of natural logarithm of N as N runs from 1 to infinity?

Comment: Do you mean $\log1+\dots+\log N$? Running the sum to infinity wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum from 1 to n
is the log of n!.
Look up Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $\log(1)+\cdots+\log(N)$, then

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N\log(i)=\log(\Gamma(N+1))
\end{align}